# I can't resize or move elements on Intellij IDEA GUI designer

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just want to drag and drop them like in Netbeans.

is there any way to get functionality of Netbeans or Eclipse in IDEA?

Comment: Your question is very vague. You talk about resixing and moving as well as drag and drop. Which is it? You need to give us specific examples of functionality that is 'missing' from IntelliJ.

Comment: When you say GUI designer are you talking about the plugin to design SWING visual interfaces?

Comment: yes i´m talking about swing designer.. i mean, when i want to grow or shrink a component, i can´t. I want to put them in any place on the JPanel.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I have solved it. You need to create a new row before dragging any new elements. In the left side you will see small green boxes for each row. Right click on the last row's green box and then choose "Insert row after this". Then you can drag and drop any new elements into your newly created row.

[image: Creating new row for adding new elements]

Answer (score 2):

You can drag and drop components and alter on which part of the layout they  appear. You might need to split a column if you want the component on only the half of a parent.

[image]

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/placing-gui-components-on-a-form.html

But to set some minimum size or set if a component should grow, you need to look into properties panel of a selected component (on the left).

[image]

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/setting-component-properties.html